# Are Xbox 360 and Xbox One consoles prone to catching a virus?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

You can use the Internet Explorer app to freely browse any web site.

I couldn't find anything official in regards to my concerns.  Are Xbox consoles prone to picking up a virus when using Internet Explorer?

I would also like to know why, or why not.

Comment: The answer may be different for Xbox 360 and Xbox One.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/xbox-association-1000003/i-can-confirm-a-xbox-360-virus-26039303/) post I found, you can indeed get a virus on Xbox 360, at least. **However**, it would be a pretty rare occurrence for several reasons:

1. You can't actually download anything from IE on Xbox, so that eliminates the easiest way to get a virus. Basically, the only way to get it without connecting it to a PC would be to open a website or e-mail attachment that could, let's say, inject malicious code targeted towards Xbox into your system. Again, pretty rare nowadays with all the website safety warnings and e-mail filtering.
2. Most computer viruses target PC specific software or hardware (for example, a Windows system file, or registry) since the creators of malicious software get very little gain from targeting a gaming console. I doubt that just messing with your machine is a prime goal for most viruses.

The bad thing, though, is that game consoles don't have any virus protection systems in place, as far as I know. Also, with the Xbox One switching to Windows 10 as its OS viruses could potentially be a bigger threat for all Windows systems.
So, based on some of the research I did on this matter - yes, in theory you could get malicious software on your console, however, in practice it's nearly impossible as of now.

Comment: I wouldn't say impossible but more so unlikely but good answer. :)

Comment: I saw 2-3 cases of an Xbox 360 getting a virus (even less had actual information about how and when it happened) , which is a fairly low number for a console that has sold over 80 million units. That's why I used "nearly impossible"